# Meaning of talon-t?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is this sentence mean

> a real talon-t for puns we see!

I saw that sentence in BBC page's comments !

Comment: A link to that comment would help. What is the article about? We need more context as it looks like a play on the word "talent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is using a (fairly weak) pun to comment on a person's capability for making puns.

The sentence would usually be

> a real talent for (making) puns we see

I suspect that the puns being referred to are rather sharp or satirical or in some way exhibiting a barbed wit. Hence the writer is indicating that the pun-maker has been rather like a bird of prey, with talons - sharp claws.

They they exploit the similarity of pronunciation between **talent** and **talon** to make the contrived pun:

> a real talon-t for puns

I'm not too impressed with this pun because the writer had to resort to adding the **-t**.